# binary search tree - recursive insertion python

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to correctly construct a binary search tree with a recursive insert function that will allow me to initialize a tree and continue to add nodes (stems). Here is the code that I've done so far (newer to coding, so probably way too wordy):

```
class Binary_Search_Tree:

  class __BST_Node:

    def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value
      self.right_child = None
      self.left_child = None

  def __init__(self):
    self.__root = None
    self.__height = 0
    self.value = None

  def _recursive_insert(self, value):
    new_stem = Binary_Search_Tree.__BST_Node(value)
    if self.__root is None:
      self.__root = new_stem
      self.__root.value = new_stem.value
    else: 
      if self.__root.value > new_stem.value:
        if self.__root.right_child is None:
          self.__root.right_child = new_stem
          self.__root.right_child.value = new_stem.value
        else:
          self.__root.right_child._recursive_insert(self.__root, value)
      else:
        if self.__root.left_child is None:
          self.__root.left_child = new_stem
          self.__root.left_child.value = new_stem.value
        else:
          self.__root.left_child._recursive_insert(self.__root, value)

  def insert_element(self, value):
    element_to_insert = self._recursive_insert(value)
    return element_to_insert
```

I then try to add values to this new tree in the main method:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  new = Binary_Search_Tree()
  new.insert_element(23)
  new.insert_element(42)
  new.insert_element(8)
  new.insert_element(15)
  new.insert_element(4)
  new.insert_element(16)
```

The error that I keep getting is: `'__BST_Node' object has no attribute '_recursive_insert'` This pops up after inserting the first element, so I'm guessing the error occurs somewhere in the else statement. If anyone can figure out where my error is or has any tips on how to make this code more readable/user friendly, I'd be appreciative!

Comment: 1. Fix your indentation. 2 Please post all your code, including `insert_element`.

Comment: Fixed indentation and posted the rest of the code! Sorry about those previous mistakes :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
self.__root.right_child._recursive_insert(self.__root, value)
```

As well as this:

```
self.__root.left_child._recursive_insert(self.__root, value)
```

You've defined `_recursive_insert` to be a method of `Binary_Search_Tree`, but you're calling it with an instance of `__BST_Node`, in `self.__root.xxxxx_child._recursive_insert`, where `xxxx_child` is an instance of BST_Node.

---

In fact, your entire `_recursive_insert` function leaves something to be desired. You're not returning anything from it, but you are assigning it's (non-existent) return value to something in `insert_element`.

Fixed code:

```
def _recursive_insert(self, root, value):
    new_stem = Binary_Search_Tree.__BST_Node(value)

    if root is None:
        root = new_stem

    else: 
        if root.value < new_stem.value:
            if root.right_child is None:
                root.right_child = new_stem
            else:
                root = self._recursive_insert(root.right_child, value)

        elif root.value > new_stem.value:
            if root.left_child is None:
                root.left_child = new_stem
            else:
                root = self._recursive_insert(root.left_child, value)

        return root

def insert_element(self, value):
    self.__root = self._recursive_insert(self.__root, value)
    return element_to_insert
```

1. Your function did not return an updated root
2. Your function does not handle a case when the value being inserted would be equal to an existing value, causing spurious entries.
3. With each recursive call, your function was being passed the same values, so it would not be able to know what to do. A new parameter for the node must be passed across calls. This makes it possible to establish a base case and return.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I tend to get muddled in my instances and I'm trying to improve my knowledge of when and what I'm calling and where the instances originate. Your solution was effective!